# Remove a row and set back the same ID to next row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have HTML rows containing IDs, like

```
1
2
3
4
```

When I remove ID 2 with jQuery I want that ID 3 should set to 2, like

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: You know that `id` cannot start with 'number' ... right? And, what are 'HTML rows' ? you mean TABLE rows ...?

Comment: 9 questions, no accepted answers. Never a good sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were few mistakes in your code, try this code it works

```
$(".clickhere").click(function(){

    $("table tr:eq("+1+")").remove();
    var i=0 // note this is the removed tr index or id
    var count = $("table tr").size();    
    for (j=i; j<count; j++)
    {
         $("table tr:eq("+(j)+")").attr("id", j+1); 
         $("table tr:eq("+(j)+")").find("td").text(j+1); 
    }
});
```

for live demo try this at [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamranali/5Qvtj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can change id with `$("#3").attr("id","2");`

Although it would be a better ideia if you select your table row with the `eq()` selector. For example, just use an `id="tableid"` in your table, and select the first tr with:

```
//Select the first tr
$('#tableid tr:eq(0)')
//Select the second tr
$('#tableid tr:eq(1)')
//Select the third tr
$('#tableid tr:eq(2)')
//an so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have created a demo code below please refer the code below

**HTML**

```
<div class="remTable">
<table style="width:50%; border:1px solid red; float:left" >
<tr id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td>2</td></tr>
<tr id="3"><td>3</td></tr>
<tr id="4"><td>4</td></tr>

</table>
<input type="button" name="click" class="clickhere" value="click"/>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".clickhere").click(function(){
    var count = $("table tr").size();
    $("table tr:eq("+1+")").remove();
    var i=1 // note this is the removed tr index or id
    for (j=i; j<count; j++)
    {
         $("table tr:eq("+(j)+")").attr("id", j+1); 
    }
});
```

Note: I have only changed the id of the tr and not the data inside the td so when u execute the code, u will see

1

3

4

but the id's of tr will be

1

2

3